# .Net Partial View Knockout Js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a partial view which I'm loading using `Ajax.actionlink` binding with the following code in a viewmodel js file

```
function ViewModel() {
this.Idnum = ko.observable();
this.Name = ko.observable();
return this;
}
function InitializeViewModel() {
ViewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, $('#vBinder')[0]);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
InitializeCardViewModel();
})
```

vBinder is the id of the Div tag where the partial view is loaded
The problem is that everything works fine in the first load, but the second load throws an exception:

> TypeError: ViewModel is not a constructor

Any help would sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the viewmodel definition with an instance of the viewmodel:

```
ViewModel = new ViewModel();
```

IE on the first load, it works fine but as soon as this line has run, on subsequent invocations, you can no longer do `new ViewModel()` because `ViewModel` is no longer a constructor function.  Use a different name for the instance of your viewmodel:

```
function InitializeViewModel() {
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#vBinder')[0]);
}
```

Comment: I did as You had shown, Now the error i get is

    TypeError: ViewModel.Idnum is not a function

What Am I supposed to do now. Sorry for the inconvenience, but i'm completely new to Knockout.

Comment: Thanks & Can you please guide me a bit here

Comment: Sounds like you've got other code elsewhere that is calling into the viewmodel - you might need to move the `vm` variable above into a scope wider than the `InitializeViewModel` function and then access `vm.Idnum` rather than `ViewModel.Idnum` in other places.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response . Any reference links that might be helpful for this scenario , Atleast for widening the scope of the declared variable . ?

Comment: Just move it outside of the function.  As for knockout - the main website has a number of examples in the documentation plus some live examples - both linked across the top of the website.

Comment: Thanks . I Did it .  I declared it as a global variable and then initialized it. It worked like a charm. Thanks a ton.